# What is the correct placement of adverb? What is the difference in meaning?

Tags: adverbs

(1) It would have never worked.

(2) It would never have worked.

(3) It never would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

The adverb 'never' is a frequency adverb and as such needs to be in mid-position. Mid-position adverbs are usually placed between the last auxiliary verb and the main verb. 'would have never worked'.

Some speakers move it around in this general area as your 3 examples have done. When you do that it's necessary to put a bit of stress on 'never' to signal that you want it to stand out. **never** would have worked/ or would **never** have worked.

On a side note, we don't usually put frequency adverbs at the beginning, (initial position) or at the end, (final position) of a sentence.

In English, if you place a word where it *normally* doesn't go, you have to put stress on it to show what you are emphasising.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wondering if I can use all of these in formal writing, or can I only use the standard one.

Answer (score 0):

All three are correct, and have identical meanings.